# What programmable switch to use on a 220 Volts AC load?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm building a circuit using PIC IC, to control the switching of a 220 Volts AC load. My idea is that the switch keeps supplying power indefinitely to the load when PIC is giving the switch an active low signal, and stops the power when PIC gives it an active high signal, and the power should remain OFF until the PIC is manually reset.
What switch would best serve my purpose? I'd prefer a simpler option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should happen after the PIC has disabled the load but then the PIC tries to re-enable the load before a reset?

Comment: Look up SSR e.g. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/LCB110-1992.pdf You said nothing about the load current.

Comment: That's a normally closed switch. I don't quite understand what you mean by "and the power should remain OFF until the PIC is manually reset". Do you mean the PIC can send random stuff after it turns off the switch [the first time]? Why would that happen? You could probably fix it with some sample and hold circuit, but I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you're formulating here.

Comment: this is not easy to answer,  if your load is a house the simplest answer if different to if your load is a nightlight, or a pump, or a water heater.

Comment: You have to be more specific in your answer. Please, note that the type of switch may be highly dependant on the type of load: mostly resistive, inductive (motors, heaters), capacitive...

Comment: Ok lets say its house load. And I don't mean to send any random stuff but hold that condition until reset manually.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for a relay to do the switching. More information has been written about that on the Internet than I can possibly rehash here -- Google for a tutorial on electrical relays.

You should expect to use a low voltage transistor such as a BSS138 or similar to allow the PIC to control a relay power supply voltage (ex. 12V) that will then control the relay which can then switch many amps at your target voltage.

Spend a little time investigating the switch transistor (N vs. P), pull down / pull up resistors and maybe some glue logic to make sure that your circuit stays in the states you want it too, as you need hardware to enforce state when your PIC is in reset (or blank!)

E: OP has stated he's using a 5V PIC18F452; added content below in a comment. Still would recommend using the PIC I/O to fire a transistor that switches 12V into a relay as 12V relays are more common than 5V models and the current sourcing of this PIC is a bit anemic.

Comment: How many volts output can PIC 18F452 give?

Comment: I sure hope you can tell me -- have you read the datasheet? It will output up the VCC of the part. Then, check how much current you are sourcing (or sinking) from the IO pin to see how close to the actual voltage it will be. The specs you are looking for are VOL and VOH.

Comment: This IC operates on 5 V. As far as the details are concerned the Data Sheet doesn't mention voltage levels. And I don't have the hardware for now so I can't test the output; I want to analyze the circuit theoretically and simulate it before taking to hardware.

Comment: Ok, so your IO is 5V capable. Also, I assure you that the PIC datasheet has the information you need. Look at section 22.2, page 266 of DS39564C. For your analysis, you see that Microchip guarantees across temperature, when sourcing 3mA out of an IO pin, you will get at minimum VDD - 0.7V (I don't know if you are using I or E parts). You can add margin to this number, and find a 5V relay. Personally, I would still use a 12V relay and use the IO to toggle a transistor that feeds the relay 12V.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was referring some other data sheet that doesn't mention any values. I can take it forward now.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any further assistance / feel free to mark as 'accepted' if you're good to go. :)

Comment: Well I guess I need further assistance right here :D how to mark accepted, I can't see any such option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers -- there should be a checkbox you can tag.